# Checking an array in Ruby to see if an object.name exists

Tags: ruby

I am making a todo list program in Ruby. I have declared two classes List and Task. List is initialized with an empty array whilst Task has a name and a status (status is initialized as "incomplete") on creating a new Task. I want to edit the createtask method so I can check the task array of the List to see if a task already exists and if it does I don't want to create a new task. How would I do this?

```
class Task
    attr_accessor :name, :status
    def initialize(name, status="incomplete")
       @name = name
       @status = status
    end

   def to_s
      "#{name.capitalize}: #{status.capitalize}"
   end


end

class List
    attr_accessor :tasksarray
    def initialize
        @tasksarray = []
    end

    def create_task(name)
        new_task = Task.new(name)
        tasksarray.push(new_task)
        puts "New task #{new_task.name} has been added with status #{new_task.status}"
    end
```

Comment: I would use a Hash instead of an array, then checking if it allready exists is easy like  tasks[taskname].nil ?

Comment: Do you wish to create one list or several lists?

Comment: I already accomplished making the task list using a simple hash key value pair way but I work as a product manager at a rails firm and the top rails guy said I should try and learn everything from a object orientated way from the start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A method that can help you out here is [`detect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect) (it's also called `find`, same method, different name) in the Enumerable mixin.

Use it to pass each element of your list to a block, it will find the first element for which the block returns `true`.
If no element is found, it returns `nil`.

In your case, you want to check whether an element has the same name as the one you're giving:

```
existing_task = @tasksarray.detect { |task| task.name == name }
if existing_task
  puts "Not adding new task, found existing task with status #{ existing_task.status }"
else
  new_task = Task.new(name)
  @tasksarray.push(new_task)
  puts "New task #{new_task.name} has been added with status #{new_task.status}"
end
```

You could to the same with Enumerable#any?

Comment: I did it using         if tasksarray.any? {|x| x.name == name}
            puts "This task already exists"
        else
        new_task = Task.new(name)

Comment: Yes, it's basically the same! I only searched up the existing one so you can print the status, but your solution is excellent.

Answer (score 0):

The comment you left on your question suggests that you only want a single list of tasks. You can do that by creating a class `List`, but you won't be creating instances of that class. Instead, the class itself will hold the list of tasks in a *class instance variable*. Consider the following.

**Code**

```
class Task
  attr_accessor :name, :status
  def initialize(name, status)
    @name = name
    @status = status
  end
end

class List
  singleton_class.send(:attr_reader, :tasks)
  @tasks = []

  def self.create_task(name, status="incomplete")
    return nil if tasks.any? { |task| task.name == name }
    new_task = Task.new(name, status)
    tasks << new_task
    new_task
  end
end
```

Notice that I've removed the `puts` statements. That makes the methods more robust. We can provide an explanation in a separate method:

```
def explain(name, task)
  if task
    puts "New task '#{name}' with status '#{task.status}' has been added" 
  else
    puts "'#{name}' is already in the list of tasks"
  end
end
```

**Examples**

```
name = "Take out the papers"
task = List.create_task(name, "will do soon")
  #=> #<Task:0x007ffa2a161058 @name="Take out the papers", @status="will do soon">
explain(name, task)
  # New task 'Take out the papers' with status 'will do soon' has been added

name = "and the trash"
task = List.create_task(name)
  #=> #<Task:0x007ffa2a149f20 @name="and the trash", @status="incomplete"> 
explain(name, task)
  # New task 'and the trash' with status 'incomplete' has been added

name = "Take out the papers"
task = List.create_task(name)
  #=> nil 
explain(name, task)    
  # 'Take out the papers' is already in the list of tasks

List.tasks
  #=> [#<Task:0x007ffa2a161058 @name="Take out the papers", @status="will do soon">,
  #    #<Task:0x007ffa2a149f20 @name="and the trash", @status="incomplete">]
List.tasks[1].name
  #=> "and the trash"
```

**Discussion**

Note that, since we will not be creating instances of `List`, that class has no `initialize` method. The line:

```
singleton_class.send(:attr_reader, :tasks)
```

sends the method [Module#attr_reader](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader) with argument `:tasks` to `List`'s singleton class, thereby creating a getter for `@tasks`. Three other ways this is commonly done are:

```
singleton_class.class_eval{attr_reader :tasks}
```

and

```
class << self
  attr_reader :tasks
end
```

and

```
module A
  attr_reader :tasks
end

class Klass
  extend A
end
```

**Improving what we have**

Since we are neither creating instances of `List` nor subclassing that class, we could make `List` a module, which would draw attention to the fact that we are not making use of the properties that distinguish a class from a module.

Rather than having instance variables `@name` and `@status`, it might makes sense to have a single instance variable that is a hash, that we might call `@task`. Among other things, that would make it easier if later we wished to add additional task attributes.

To determine if a task is in the list of tasks, we need to step through an array.  If there are many tasks, that would be relatively inefficient. We could speed that up considerably by making the list a hash, whose keys are names of tasks and whose values are the task instances. That way, we only have to check to see if the hash has a key `name`, which is very fast.<sup>1</sup>.

In sum, let's do the following:

- Replace the instance variables `@name` and `@status` in `Tasks` with a hash.
- Replace the instance variable `@task` with a hash.
- Make `List` a module rather than a class.

*Revised code*

```
class Task
  attr_accessor :task
  def initialize(name, status)
    @task = { name: name, status: status }
  end
end

module List
  singleton_class.send(:attr_reader, :tasks)
  @tasks = {}
  def self.create_task(name, status = 'incomplete')
    return nil if tasks.key?(name)
    task = Task.new(name, status)
    @tasks[name] = task 
    task
  end
end

def explain(name, task)
  if task
    puts "New task '#{name}' with status '#{task.task[:status]}' has been added" 
  else
    puts "'#{name}' is already in the list of tasks"
  end
end
```

*Examples*

```
name = "Take out the papers"
task = List.create_task(name, "real soon now")
  #=> #<Task:0x007f802305cf30 @task={:name=>"Take out the papers",
  #                                  :status=>"real soon now"}> 
explain(name, task)
  # New task 'Take out the papers' with status 'real soon now' has been added

name = "and the trash"
task = List.create_task(name)
  #=> #<Task:0x007f8023045088 @task={:name=>"and the trash",
  #                                  :status=>"incomplete"}> 
explain(name, task)
  # New task 'and the trash' with status 'incomplete' has been added

name = "Take out the papers"
task = List.create_task(name)
  #=> nil 
explain(name, task)
  # 'Take out the papers' is already in the list of tasks

List.tasks
  #=> {"Take out the papers"=>#<Task:0x007f802305cf30
  #      @task={:name=>"Take out the papers", :status=>"real soon now"}>,
  #    "and the trash"=>#<Task:0x007f8023045088
  #      @task={:name=>"and the trash", :status=>"incomplete"}>} 
List.tasks["Take out the papers"].task[:status]
  #=> "real soon now"
```

<sup>1 This has the drawback of having the name of each task in two places (in the list hash and in the corresponding task instance variable (hash). In general, such duplication is not good programming practice. More experienced coders could probably offer advice here.</sup>